# How do i get the argv[0]?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

In C++ i was getting the app path without the app name at the end by saying:

```
 std::string dir = dirname(argv[0]);
```

and it worked without any problems, but when i planned to use cocoa it said:

error: 'argv' was not declared in this scope and now i'm lost i have tried:

```
NSArray *args = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];

std::string dir = dirname(args);
```

but without any luck, please help me out guys!

ps: i have changed the files from .m to .mm already in case you want to know

Comment: Have you looked in the main.m file of your project?

Comment: yes, but my functions is placed in the delegate and linked to some objects that is going be displayed on the screen, it would be useless to place them inside the main.m

Comment: just copy it into a global.

Comment: @KenAspeslagh: It's already retrievable globally. Either way, though, that isn't the best way to get the parent directory of the executable if you have Cocoa available.

Comment: `argv` isn't available because it's declared as an argument to `main`, and you tried to use it somewhere outside of `main`. Because it's one of `main`'s arguments, you can only use it within your implementation of `main`. `dirname` won't work on an NSArray object;  for one thing, it requires a single string, not an array of them, and for another, it requires a C string (I don't know whether there's a std::string version), not an NSString.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you get the app path:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saying

```
std::string dir = dirname(args);
```

try the following:

```
NSArray *args = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
NSString* arg0 = args[0];
std::string dir = dirname([arg0 fileSystemRepresentation]);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It wont compile, it says now:  'args' was not declared in this scope
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Comment: This definitely works. What data type does your dirname function expect? When it's char*, you can simply cast (char*)[arg0 fileSystemRepresentation].